# What repair options are available for Thinkpad Stack hard drives?

Tags: external-hard-drive, thinkpad, repair

I really like the ThinkPad Stack lineup and was sad to see it go discontinued. For context, here's the product:

[image]

I still use it for its powerbank and mobile NAS functionality. However, the 1TB hard drive stopped working. I'm guessing its due to frequent travels and bouncing around in my bag or something like that.

Regardless, I'd like to continue using the product. I don't really care about my data, there was nothing important on the ThinkPad Stack hard drive and I'm content to let it be wiped away into the ether. However, the hardware itself is more of a concern for me.

I brought the product into a Lenovo store and they told me that they don't repair this product and my only option was to buy a new one. I was in a hurry so I didn't stop to learn more. When I did try to buy one, I saw that they are basically impossible to find now -- all but disappeared from the market (new and 2nd hand).

I'm guessing Lenovo doesn't place this type of thing high on their priorities at the moment. I tried to see what aftermarket solutions are available and found a decent guide:

https://www.gillware.com/hard-drive-data-recovery/hard-drive-repair-faq/

Which seems to suggest that it's better to discard the broken drive and replace it with a new one. Again, I'm fine with letting my data go unrecovered, but I'm not sure that my hardware needs will be addressed in the aftermarket. For example, Stack uses proprietary pogo peg magnetic thingies to transfer power and data throughout the modular components. This allows for functions like:

- The Stack router draws power from the power bank
- The Stack router has an attached storage in the form of the hard
  drive
- The Stack speaker can play media on the attached hard drive
- Ect

### Question

Given that I don't give a hoot about my data and face much difficulty in finding new/second-hand replacements, and given that I just want a ThinkPad Stack hard drive that works, is a third-party data recovery service appropriate for me? If not, what options might I also want to explore?

One acceptable solution I can think of off the top of my head is to gut the hard drive, put a new one in, connect it to the pogo peg thingies, and reseal the case. Old model, new guts. But I don't know, maybe there is a better way to get the device to work again.

Comment: My advice would be to invest your money in new hardware.

Answer (score 2):

> […] is a third-party data recovery service appropriate for me?

Data recovery service does what it says: they recover your data, not fix your device.

> One acceptable solution I can think of off the top of my head is to gut the hard drive, put a new one in, connect it to the pogo peg thingies, and reseal the case.

That sounds like a plan. It's most likely using a bog-standard SATA HDD that can easily be replaced. Confirm that that's the case before buying a new drive.

Getting a new drive to work may be a challenge if the device makes some assumptions about drive's format. Inspecting the original drive could help, but given that it's dead that's not an option. So I'd suggest to try it on an unused drive you may have lying around or a cheap used one before buying a proper replacement.

Then take this into consideration:

- Match the form factor. If the original HDD is 2.5", you won't fit in a 3.5" drive or vice versa.
- Match the rotational speed. It will most likely be either 5400 rpm or 7200 rpm. 5900 rpm is also not unheard of. HDDs with higher rpm will be faster, but they will draw more power and the device may not be designed to provide more than the original HDD is expected to use.
- The larger the drive capacity, the faster sequential transfers will be. That won't necessarily translate to random access though.
- Avoid SMR drives. These are cheaper, but their data storage method makes them problematic in some use cases.